# pod search "XXX" and return Unable to find

Tags: search, cocoapods

I am sure that `pod trunk push XXX.podspec` is success, but i can search XXX.

Run `pod search XXX`

return `Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching XXX`

I have tried `pod setup` and `pod repo update`, that is dosen't work.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `rm ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/search_index.json`

and `pod search XXX`

this is work for me!